# Using Engine Starter Fluid to Decontaminate Brake Pads

Tags: brakes, disc-brake, hydraulic-disc-brake, brake-pads

I have some hydraulic disc brakes, and for one reason or another they get contaminated. My dad (who's worked on cars for ages) told me to use engine starter fluid, but I'm kind of skeptical about this. I know they make some brake cleaners, but would starter fluid accomplish the same task without negative side effects?

Comment: For rotors maybe (though I wouldn't). For pads - do you know what the posts are made of? Is it compatible with the starter fluid? Do you know what's in the fluid?

Comment: They're metallic brake pads. I don't know what you mean by posts. As far as the starter fluid goes, it's just standard Supertech Engine Starting Fluid. I've used the starter fluid for getting grease off my clothes since I know it just wicks away grease. But I'm a little more hesitant on my nice brakes

Comment: Posts was meant to be pads - autocorrect bites again. You're right to be hesitant, though (all-) metal pads should be OK.

Comment: Do you think it would change things if I had organic brake pads?

Comment: Potentially yes - engine starter fluid is quite a powerful organic solvent, and there's a chance of it weakening the pads or changing the surface. Possibly not in an obvious way. Given that brake manufacturers make or endorse certain cleaning solutions I'd go for those, though with metal parts (rotors/rims for v-brakes) I use meths to clean/degrease.

Comment: Historically, "starter fluid" is pure ether, though I suppose the newer stuff has additives to prevent "huffing".

Comment: If the pads are brand new and were contaminated you may get them as dry as possible and then sand them down a tiny bit. Lay the sandpaper on a flat surface and drag the pad around in circles so that you get an even sand. This method is used when they are squeeling from not being bed in properly.

I agree that brake cleaner/starter fluid on organic pads could mess them up, I would be hesitant to use it on metallic ones as well. Manufacturers would say replace them. But you know how that goes ;)

Comment: Haha yeah I sanded them down and they're a lot better now, but starter fluid would be, well, easier and cheaper. As far as manufacturer recommendations...

Comment: About thirty years ago I helped my dad dig a hole in the yard. We buried a 55 gallon drum filled with various aggregate. It was a dry well, a place to pour motor oil and other chemicals! Point is, just because it works doesn't mean we should do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seeing that starter fluid could contain any number of things, I wouldn't.

You can simply use isopropyl alcohol. Very cheap, typically most grocery stores would stock it and you want to get as simple and pure as possible. ie. don't buy the scented ones.

In liquid form, you can easily use a toothbrush and give them a good clean. It will decrease and get most grime out and put you back to step 1 of bedding in the pads. I have use this a number of times to clean off even DOT 5 from pads.

With isopropyl alcohol it doesn't matter if they are sintered or organic pads and any excess isopropyl alcohol will simply evaporate with minimal residue. The key is to brush and 'wash' of as much as possible and not to simply soak them.